# Facebook Instant Articles horizontal swipe not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

The horizontal swipe feature used to scroll through previous articles from the current one being read doesn't seem to consistently work.

Basically, when I tap on an article in the page's news feed, it's showing the correct article, and I can usually swipe to the right to view the latest published article. But that's it. I cannot view the other dozen articles in my production list.

The markup for each article seems fine from what I can see, no inconsistencies. But of course, I must be missing something.

I'm writing these articles in Wordpress and publishing them using the WP Instant Articles plugin.

The image below shows what I mean by only viewing one other article. Any input on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

[image: Example article]